# can we install 64bit jdk on 32bit CentOS

Tags: java, installation, centos, java-6, centos5

I have a 64bit jdk 1.6 installer . Can I install java on centos 5.8 32 bit using a 64 bit installer. If so what would be the command to achieve the same.

TIA.

Comment: No you can't because a 32 bits OS doesn't provide 64 bits support.  The reverse is true though, you can install a 32 bits program on a 64 bits Linux.

Comment: @fvu: I think you should post an answer for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you can't because a 32 bits OS doesn't provide 64 bits support. The reverse is true though, you can install a 32 bits program on a 64 bits Linux.

Specifically in the case of Java program though, except for those programs that require huge heaps you should be able to get the to run on both a 32 bits or 64 bits JDK, so it's worth a try to install the 32 bits JDK and try to execute the application.

Answer (score 1):

Simply, no you can't.  To run a 64-bit application, you need an OS that supports 64-bit apps, and a 32-bit OS does not do this.